# React webpack bundle

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with webpack. My webpack.config.js file is listed bellow. It worked fine before I reinstall my mac. Now I am getting this error:

```
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory
```

All dependencies are ok, I've try many times to remove node_modules and reinstall them. Can someone help me with this problem?

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/dist/bundles");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/src");

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        SRC_DIR + "/js/index.js",
        SRC_DIR + "/scss/index.scss"
    ],
    output: {path: DIST_DIR, filename: 'bundle.js'},
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css")
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    "css!sass")
            },
            {
                test: [/\.js$/, /\.es6$/],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                  cacheDirectory: true,
                  presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                }
              }
        ]
    }
};
```

Package.json dependencies are:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "bulma": "^0.2.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta5",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
```

Comment: Have you added presets es2015 & react in .babelrc file?

Comment: Yeah, missing .bablerc was the problem. But previously it worked without this file. Anyway, thank you very much. :)